# Laravel select() returns empty value with Polymorphic relation and Cross Join

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have 4 tables: `tv_shows`, `tv_show_episodes`, `languages`, and `languageables`

Every TV show may have many languages by a polymorphic relationship.
And I intent to filter TV shows by languages. meanwhile I am also sorting TV shows by air date of episodes.

```php
TvShow::select([
    'tv_shows.*',
    'tv_show_episodes.id as episode_id',
    'tv_show_episodes.name as episode_name',
    'tv_show_episodes.air_date as episode_air_date',
    'tv_show_episodes.season_number',
    'tv_show_episodes.episode_number',
    'tv_show_episodes.still_path',
])
->crossJoin('tv_show_episodes', 'tv_shows.id', '=', 'tv_show_episodes.tv_show_id')
->whereRaw('timestamp(concat(tv_show_episodes.air_date, " ", tv_shows.airs_time)) <= NOW()')
->orderByRaw('timestamp(concat(tv_show_episodes.air_date, " ", tv_shows.airs_time)) DESC')
->when($request->has('languages'), function($query) {
    $query->whereHas('languages', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->whereIn('iso_639_1', explode(',', request('languages')));
    });
})->paginate(10)
```

`TvShow.php`

```
public function languages()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Language::class, 'languageable');
}
```

At the end, I paginate them by 10. When I see that `total` is fine and returns the correct value.but `data` is always empty.

```
{
    "current_page":1,
    "data":[],
    "from":null,
    "last_page":1760,
    "per_page":10,
    "to":null,
    "total":17600
}
```

And the interesting thing is when I remove the `select()` method from above query, Everything goes fine.

I need those episodes info beside TV Shows. and I want to know what is the reason of that ?

Comment: can you show how you `paginate` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below answer,

```
  TvShow::selectRaw('`tv_shows`.*, `tv_show_episodes`.`id` as `episode_id`, `tv_show_episodes`.`name` as `episode_name`, `tv_show_episodes`.`air_date` as `episode_air_date`, `tv_show_episodes`.`season_number`, `tv_show_episodes`.`episode_number`, `tv_show_episodes`.`still_path`')
->crossJoin('tv_show_episodes', 'tv_shows.id', '=', 'tv_show_episodes.tv_show_id')
->whereRaw('timestamp(concat(tv_show_episodes.air_date, " ", tv_shows.airs_time)) <= NOW()')
->orderByRaw('timestamp(concat(tv_show_episodes.air_date, " ", tv_shows.airs_time)) DESC')
->when($request->has('languages'), function($query) {
    $query->whereHas('languages', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->whereIn('iso_639_1', explode(',', request('languages')));
    });
})->paginate(10)
```

Here, `TvShow` is your model.
hope this help you.